# How to create new console sessions in Python and work with them

Tags: python, bash, python-2.7, terminal, subprocess

I'm trying to figure out how to work with consoles in Python. Let's say, I have a Python2 script. And this script should create 3 consoles (bash or any other) and provide different commands to them.

Example:

- Console #1 will be responsible for telnetting
- Console #2 for pinging
- Console #3 will be responsible for new ssh access

What I've found so far is **subprocess** module.

I can use this

```
import subprocess
term1 = subprocess.Popen(['open', '-a', 'Terminal'])
```

But I still cannot find how to send a command to **term1**

Thank you.

Comment: If I understand well, the key problem here is that you want to communicate with the program running _inside_ of the terminal. Not with the terminal itself.

Comment: @SylvainLeroux no. My problem is I need to communicate with the each  terminal itself and read output from all of them.

Comment: Apparently, I don't clearly understand you issue. To my mind, a _terminal_ (aka _console_) is not much more than the GUI program that display the window and route I/O from/to a PTY to some host program. That host program is the really "useful thing": it might be a shell (bash, ssh), a `ping` command, or any other "console-mode" program (i.e.: reading from _stdin_, writing to _stdout_). So I don't clearly understand what you want to say by _" I need to communicate with the each terminal itself"_

Comment: @SylvainLeroux in my particular case I have to have 3 consoles. And run 3 different commands. Each command for each console. My problem is after running first console with "tcprelay --portoffset 10000 873 23" command I cannot run the second one and third one also. My script runs first command itself without opening new console session. That's why I need to have 3 console session for 3 commands

Comment: You probably need [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/multiprocessing.html)

Answer (score 2):

I've tested that using `xterm` on Linux. Might be adapted to MacOS X terminal without too much problems ... I hope.

The key idea is to create an anonymous pipe from Python, then instruct the shell running inside of the terminal emulator to read from that pipe:

```
import os
output, input = os.pipe()
term = subprocess.Popen("xterm -e 'bash </dev/fd/{}'".format(output),shell=True)

f = os.fdopen(input,"wt")

# output as much as command as you want. `flush` between them ... to flush data
f.writelines("echo toto\n")
f.flush()

f.close()
```

Producing that output on the GUI terminal emulator:

[image: toto]

If you want read and write, you have to open two pipes -- but beware of dead-lock if you fill the pipe in one direction:

```
>>> import os
>>> output1, input1 = os.pipe()
>>> output2, input2 = os.pipe()
>>> term = subprocess.Popen("xterm -e 'bash </dev/fd/{} >/dev/fd/{}'".format(output1,input2),shell=True)
>>> 
>>> fin = os.fdopen(input1,"wt")
>>> fout = os.fdopen(output2,"rt")
>>> 
# FOR EXPERIMENTAL PURPOSE ONLY: SUBJECT TO DEAD-LOCK !!!
>>> fin.writelines("date\n")
>>> fin.flush()
>>> 
>>> print fout.readline()

Thu Aug 14 23:50:15 CEST 2014

>>> 
>>> fin.close()
>>> fout.close()
```

---

That being said, in that configuration, the only interest in having a terminal opened is to display potential *stderr* output on the GUI display.

If you only need to communicate with the underlying command (bash, ping, ...), you don't really need a terminal, just to connect to the corresponding subprocess standard I/O as explained in an other answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have the ability to communicate with your subprocess its best to use `subprocess.popen`.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen

This way you can create a stdin and stout to communicate with the process. As shown in the link above you simply add them to the popen argument:

```
subprocess.Popen(args, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE)
```

There is also `popen.communicate(input= 'your input')`.

That will wait for the command to finish.

Comment: That was my first thought too, but I've tried that on Linux using `xterm` without success. Could you confirm this works with MacOS X `Terminal` ?

Comment: your code should look something like: term1 = subprocess.Popen(['open', '-a', 'Terminal'], stdin=PIPE,stdout = PIPE)  that way you can just use: return_info = term1.communicate(input="your_input") and it should give you a return.